# Ruby On Rails 4.1 prepending site url to hash links

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, link-to, hashbang, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to make some foundation tabs working in rails 4, so I've created the necessary markup.

The links triggering tab switch are common hash links (e.g. "#my-tab").
When I click on one of those links, rails automatically replace the href attribute with a full url, like so:
http://my-site.dev/index#my-tab

This simply breaks the behaviour of tabs.

Is there something I'm not seeing or some rails configuration?

**UPDATE**

I found out it was Turbolinks. It's not enough to disable turbolink for every single link, because it's the turbolinks.js itself causing this behaviour.

I had to completely disable turbolinks by removing the line:

```
// require turbolinks
```

from my assets/javascripts/application.js.

If anybody comes up with a more atomic and elegant solution, I will be glad to mark the answer as correct!

Comment: What code are you using to generate the tabs? ie are you using `link_to`?

Comment: How do you expect the url to be? how was it before clicking on the link?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using `link_to` to generate the anchor link.

`link_to` method invocation looks as follows:

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

`options` hash is what gets passed to `url_for` method. One of the options you can use in there is:

```
:anchor => 'my-tab'
```

Which should generate a simple `#my-tab` link you need.